# VB.NET Picturebox on top of MDI Child

Tags: vb.net, picturebox, mdi

Any idea why a picturebox in a MDI parent would show on top of a MDI child? (even when MDI child = topmost)

When calling picturebox.SendToBack the picturebox disappears in the MDI parent.

Comment: MDI child windows are parented to the MdiClient window.  The dark-gray window inside the Mdi parent window.  A control you put on the parent is going to overlap a child window since it is on top of the client window.  SendToBack is going to make it disappear behind the client window.  You'll have to use the Dock property on such a control to shrink the client window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was, created a borderless form with the picturebox on it, and threw it on the MDI parent as a MDI child, seems to do the job!