# Picturebox control is overlaping child form

Tags: c#, mdiparent

In an mdi parent form i display one image using PictureBox and i am trying to open form but image is overlaping the form.

I am allready try BringToFront(), SendToBack(), TopMost but still not working.

[image]

Comment: you solve it by looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814968/vb-net-picturebox-on-top-of-mdi-child

Comment: @Archlight When form is not maximized its working when i am maximize it close and minimize and maximize button display. http://prntscr.com/4gyjjx

Comment: http://bobpowell.net/mdiback.aspx

Comment: @HansPassant I dont want to you background image